# Pass a reference to a constructor

Tags: c++, reference

I am sorry if this meight be a really simple question but i am new to c++ and working on a simple vocable trainer for understanding c++. (come from java..)

I'd like to pass a `const FileManager` as reference to my Logic. But i don't get it work. I don't want to have a copy or such.

So i tried it like this: (the main)

```
FileManager& file = FileManager();
Logic logic = Logic(file);
```

Inside of the Logic i'd like to store the reference:

```
class Logic
{
public:

    Logic(const FileManager& manager);
    ~Logic();

private: 
    const FileManager& m_fileManager;
};

Logic::Logic(const FileManager& manager) : 
{   
    m_fileManager = manager;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Find "constructor initializer list" in your C++ text. Reference member variables are *required* to be initialized in said-manner (as are const members).

Comment: You usually store a pointer instead of a reference as a member. Also, don’t call your classes managers. It’s confusing and most likely violates SRP. You also want to make your constructor `explicit`.

Comment: @rightfold I usually store references, when that reference have to reference to an object. In the rare cases, where that reference is optionally and don't have to point to an object, I use a pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once the body of a constructor is entered, all member variables have already been initialized. Thereafter, you can only assign to them. This can't work with references - as we know, they need to be initialized when their lifetime begins.

You need to use member initializer list:

```
Logic::Logic(const FileManager& manager)
    : m_fileManager(manager) // m_fileManager is initialized here
{   
}
```

Consider if you really want a reference member. For one, they make your class non-assignable. A smart pointer might be a better choice.

Comment: So if i have that list, it is automaticaly inited? How do i correctly use it then? 

It shouldnt be assignable but regulary useable and not a copy.

Comment: +1 for the answer in general, and I wish I could +1 it again, for the mentioning of downsides to a const member reference (specifically the non-default-assignable condition).

Comment: @BennX Yes, it's automaticaly initialized when the object is constructed. If you can live without ever assigning to `Logic` object, you can keep a reference member. But make sure that it  doesn't outlive the `FileManager` object it was initialized with, because then you'll have a dangling reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your example has three flaws. The first, is that you try to initialize a none const reference with a temporary object:

```
FileManager& file = FileManager();
```

Most likely you just want to use a FileManager instance here:

```
FileManager file;
```

Second, references must be initialized. You achieve this by using the initializer list syntax:

```
Logic::Logic(const FileManager& manager) 
  : m_fileManager( manager )
{   
}
```

In addition, the initializing, you use for Logic requires that Logic is assignable. Simply use:

```
Logic logic(file);
```

If you have reference members in a class, objects of that class are not assignable by default.